# ASP JQuery Ajax, checking a list with queries between sql process ended

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql, ajax, stored-procedures

i have a list with many sql procedures, and a start button,
i need to run one by one each process and update the list
with the procedures for each process ended, someone can helpme please i spend 3 days hard.

something like this

One   ok

Two   ok

Three doing...

Four  -

public void Method()
{

SQLProcessOne();

ShowImageFinishedOne();

SQLProcessTwo();

ShowImageFinishedTwo();

SQLProcessThree();

ShowImageFinishedThree();

}

Comment: I think you need to give more information on what you are trying to do.  Are you saying you want this list to dynamically update as the processes are running to show a status?  There is not enough information in your post to give a good answer.

Comment: yes im trying to show a status for each process finished thanks

Comment: but doing one process first and then the second and the third...

Comment: There are some problems StackOverflow can't solve ...  `someone can helpme please i spend 3 days hard`  :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX and query the server after each SQL process completes.  [jQuery makes it very easy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).